# Selecting certain Data from Dataset

Tags: python

I have a Dataset which contains the data from 2014 - 2016. How could i extract the data, so that i only have the ones from 2016. The Dataset has a big size of rows.

This is an example of how the columns look: 2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your "dataset" ? A file  (and if yes what does it looks like) ? A SQL database ?

Comment: The file format is .csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic parsing. I'll assume that you know how to create an array of strings and use that as an example. A simple way of doing this is the slice the first four characters, and check if they are equal to the string `"2016"`

```
columns = ["2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00",
           "2016-02-12 00:00:00-06:00",
           "2015-05-22 00:00:00-06:00",
           "2016-11-25 00:00:00-06:00",
           "2015-10-21 00:00:00-06:00"]
desired_columns = []
for column in columns:
    if column[0:4] == "2016":
        desired_columns.append(column)
print(desired_columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the data row by row and take necessary ones using String.startswith("2016") or a regex if you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
columns = ["2014-01-01 00:00:00-06:00",
          "2016-02-12 00:00:00-06:00",
          "2015-05-22 00:00:00-06:00",
          "2016-11-25 00:00:00-06:00",
          "2015-10-21 00:00:00-06:00"]

desired_columns = [column for column in columns if '2016' in column]


print(desired_columns)
```

You can use a conditional test such as 'if 2016 in column' while running a for loop. You can then put this conditional test in a list comprehension in order to reduce your code to 1 line such as I did here. Here is your output:

```
['2016-02-12 00:00:00-06:00', '2016-11-25 00:00:00-06:00']
```